# Data Passing from One Php page to another

Tags: php

```
<a href="<?php echo $config_basedir;?>showcart.php?type=" . $type . >View   Basket/Checkout</a>
```

Above mentioned link is called by header program . I want to pass the type value while calling the showcart.php. But its passing blank value.

**EDIT**

```
<?php $type=$_GET['type']; 
echo "$type"; ?> 
<a href="<?php echo $config_basedir; ?>">Home</a>
 - <a href="<?php echo $config_basedir;?>showcart.php?type=" . $type . >View Basket/Checkout</a> 
</div>
```

Comment: Make sure your you are having a value in $type variable..

Comment: show more code, please

Comment: look. you showed us a part of php file/code. 1 - you can show us more? 2 - can you show the result html generated by this php file?

Comment: Your syntax for that link is completely messed up

Comment: Something doesn't look right here:

`<a href="
<?php echo $config_basedir;?>
showcart.php?type=" . $type . >View   Basket/Checkout</a>`

Maybe a missing "

Comment: <?php
$type=$_GET['type'];
echo "$type";
?>
<a href="<?php echo $config_basedir; ?>">Home</a> -
<a href="<?php echo $config_basedir;?>showcart.php?type=" . $type . >View Basket/Checkout</a>
</div>

Answer (score 1):

When you try to throw in the $type variable you do so from within the HTML context. You need to open php tags again and echo the $type variable where you need to

In result you will get:

```
 <a href="<?php echo $config_basedir;?>showcart.php?type=<?php echo $type; ?>">View   Basket/Checkout</a>
```

Comment: @NYS  XcelaThanks a lot for your help .. its working fine . I missed the php tag while passing the type field. Thanks again. :)

Answer (score 1):

You might as well just do it all as one echo:

```
echo "<a href='{$config_basedir}showcart.php?type={$type}'>View  Basket/Checkout</a>";
```

As you have it there are several syntax errors, such as no closing quote on your href attribute, and you are trying to concatenate with PHP outside of a PHP block.

Comment: <a href="<?php echo $config_basedir;?>showcart.php?type={$type}" . >View Basket/Checkout</a>

I have tried this. but its not working.

Comment: Watch out for `$type` - in the OP that variable comes from unfiltered user input, so it poses a XSS risk /cc @pranay.

Comment: @halfer thanks for reminding me. I will do this now.